# Using "would" instead of "used to"

Tags: used-to

It is well-known that action verbs, such as "go" can go before "would" to refer to past habits. But a friend of mine says that it cannot be used in the following example:

When l was a child, l ***would*** go to my grandpa's farm.

He insists that we should use "used to". He even didn't give any explanation. Is he correct?

Comment: You have picked up the habit of using lower case "L"  (l)  instead of uppercase i (I)  in some fonts these look the same. But don't trust that. Use Shift+i to create the right spelling.

Comment: see also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118175/would-and-used-to?rq=1  and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/247441/used-to-vs-would?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would and used to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118175/would-and-used-to)

Comment: Your friend is mistaken - ***would*** and ***used to*** are both perfectly natural for the cited context. The only contexts I can think of where they're *not* interchangeable are as in @Joachim's link. You can say ***I used to be fat*** to mean you were fat *for a relatively long time* in the past, but ***I would be fat*** is either nonsense or it means something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

"Would" has several meanings: it forms future-in-the-past sentences, it is used to form conditional clauses and it can be used for past habits.

To make it clear what sense is being used, you need some context:

> When I was a child, I would go to my grandpa's farm if the weather was fine (conditional)

> When I was a child, I would go to my grandpa's farm every summer (past habit)

Without that little bit of context, it is rather unclear. Which is why "used to" is probably clearer.

Comment: The conditional sense in your first example comes from "if", not "would". It's perfectly natural English to say, "When I was a child, I used to go to my grandpa's farm if the weather was fine." I agree with @FumbleFingers that **would** and **used to** mean the same thing in the OP.